# having an error while importing data into sql from Azure trough polybase

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-data-lake

EXTERNAL TABLE access failed due to internal error: 'Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_GetDirectoryFiles. Java exception message:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.: Error [java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.] occurred while accessing external file.'
Here is the code

```
            CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL xyz
            WITH
            IDENTITY = 'user',
            SECRET = 'your secret key'

            CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE Datalake1
            WITH
            (
            TYPE = HADOOP,
            LOCATION = 'wasbs://datastorage@datalake.blob.core.windows.net',
            CREDENTIAL = xyz
            );

            CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT dataformat4
            WITH
            (
            FORMAT_TYPE = DelimitedText,
            FORMAT_OPTIONS 
            (
                FIELD_TERMINATOR = '|',
                STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
                --DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
                --DATE_FORMAT   = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff zzz',
                DATE_FORMAT='yyyy-MM-dd',
                USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = FALSE
            )
            );
            CREATE SCHEMA ext1;
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ext1].[Membership]
            (
            [Record_Id] [bigint] NULL,
            [Practitioner_Code] [varchar](8) NULL,
            [Valid_From_Date_Time] [datetime] NULL,
            [Valid_To_Date_Time] [datetime] NULL,
            [Current_Flag] [bit] NULL
            )
            WITH 
            (
            LOCATION='/quaterly/Membership',
            DATA_SOURCE = Datalake1,
            FILE_FORMAT = dataformat4
            -- REJECT_TYPE = percentage,
            --REJECT_VALUE = 1,
            -- REJECT_SAMPLE_VALUE = 1000
            );
            SELECT * into [dbo].[Membership]
            FROM [ext].[Membership]
```

Comment: Please, add more data to the answer.

Comment: Is that you run the script in on-premise sql server

Comment: no, I am running  this code on a virtual machine